# Why VScode display"'iostream' file not found"in .h file?

Tags: c++, class, header-files

```
//vector.h
#ifndef MYVECTOR_H_
#define MYVECTOR_H_

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class vectors
{
public:
    vectors(void);
    ~vectors(void);
    vectors(int *vec,int n);
    vectors(vectors &a);
    friend vectors operator + (vectors a, vectors b);//加法
    friend vectors operator - (vectors a, vectors b);//减法
    friend vectors operator ++(vectors a);//前自增
    friend vectors operator ++(vectors a,int n);//后自增
    friend vectors operator --(vectors a);//前自减
    friend vectors operator --(vectors a,int n);//后自减
    friend vectors operator * (vectors a,vectors b);//数乘

    void Display();//显示函数

private:
    int * Vec;//向量指针
    int N;//维数
};

vectors::vectors(void)
{

}

}
#endif
```

I'm writing a header file by C++ in VScode, but VScode show me:

'iostream' file not found

In cpp file, it never happens. I think I should install all it need. And I never meet it before.So I don't know how to do with it.

Ok, I try to give more details.

I use vscode to write code. In last codes, I just used '.cpp' files, so I haven't get an error report. But in this time, I try to write my header file as above, vscode tell me:**iostream' file not found**. I can't correct it. So I ask someone for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Try deleting that line then typing it in again. There might be an invisible character hidden in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try recognize the compiler. Open command palette `CTRL+SHIFT+P`, type **C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)** and open, then choose your compiler path, for instance, `C:/MinGW/bin/g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall all C/C++ extensions in VSCODE and reload it, but before that, set **C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)** -> compiler path to **C:/MinGW/bin/g++**.